# Problema com ASP.NET ferramenta de administração de site!

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, já tirei a permissão de somente leitura da pasta e nada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clico em Escolher repositório... ele me redireciona para essa tela abaixo, e ao clicar em Teste ele exibe a informação de compatibilidade:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu sql é o 2014, já criei o registro com o **Aspnet_regsql.exe**, será que vou ter que instalar o SQL 2008? Ou esse problema do acesso negado pode ser resolvido de outra maneira? Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o seguinte usuário no diretório `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`:

[image: Membership Configuration]

Feito isso, tente configurar novamente.

Comment: Esse usuário já está lá, com permissão total! :(